# Installing Anaconda on MacOS Catalina

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, macos-catalina

When installing Anaconda3 ( https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-5.3.1-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg ) on MacOS Catalina.  It installed fine on Sierra.

The error appears on the 'Select a Destination' 'How do you want to install this software?': You cannot install Anaconda3 in this location. The Anaconda3 installer does not allow its software to be installed here.'

Answer (score 0):

Simply check on the "Install on a specific disk" then click back on "Install for me only" and it will work.

[image]

Comment: For the curious, this is a [known bug](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/836) with the [official install documentation](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/mac-os/) suggesting this exact workaround.